# How to create pine cone shaped effect of repeated pattern embossed surface with scale variation?

Tags: modeling

I am very new to Blender. I am modeling a 3D for a lipstick bottle.

[image]

How to achieve this type of effect that resembles a pine cone with repeated embossed pattern shaped like scales?

Comment: Just dropping some ideas: displacement map or normal map could do. It is also possible using the particle system. If your desired pattern is less regular and you have a bigger (complicated) area to cover then even sculpting with texture brush might be an option.

Comment: Those look like 2 different parts of the object - the red one inside, the transparent and refractive outside. In that case they should be modeled separately to allow caustics. Modeling that pattern on the surface can be cumbersome if you need all those details, you could model one flake and go with rotated array or Tissue addon

Comment: Thanks Zak, Can anyone gif the process? i have made one piece of the "fish scales pattern". 

I watched Youtube but fail to understand on the array & curve modifier. 

Appreciate your attention. Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Make a plane and Bend it

The object has two main features: it's cylindrical and it's cover with a pattern. A possible way to approach the problem could be to focus first of all on the pattern and then repeat it on a planar surface that we are going to bend.

**The pattern's tile**

First step is to model a "tile". I started from the main loop: an half circle. I built the following shape by extruding and adjusting the vertices manually keeping an eye on the flow of the edges. Then I duplicated the single petal around and cut with the knife tool the pieces outside the "ideal" square box in order to obtain a perfect match of the instances borders of the array. Mirror modifier will ensure the symmetry on the X axis. It's important to keep in mind that when a bored ends, the other should start: that's wy the scale is a little rotated and not parallel with the XY plane.

I kept it low poly because I planned to use SubSurf and to be able to make changes quickly.

[image]

*Note: there are surely better topology for the mesh; I'll present here just a sample. Keep in mind that we are going to bend it on the X direction, so there should be a good amount of edgeloops running from top to bottom.*

**Deforming a plane**

It's now time to add a few modifiers to the object:

- An *Array* modifier that replicate the object in X (set Merge option enabled)
- Another *Array* modifier that replicate the object in Y (set Merge option enabled)
- A *Simple Deform* modifier with *Bend* mode , 360 degree of rotation and a custom object (an empty previously created) to manipulate the center of rotation
- A *Subdivision Surface* modifier with Catmull Clark option to smooth the edges and increase the resolution before the final tapering
- A *Lattice* modifier to control the deformation of the cylinder along its revolution axis. It also helps in making the scales smaller toward the end once enabled *Proportional* edit mode.

[image]

The main body of the object can be said finished. You should now proceed to create the top and the bottom pieces and refining the object (removing doubles, building the inside shell, assign different materials...) once you are satisfied with the result of the modifiers. In order to edit the resulting geometry you must **apply** the modifiers before entering edit mode.

This approach that heavily take advantage of modifiers it's quite flexible and non-destructive, but it is successful be used only because your geometry has a polar symmetry.

Tissue add-on cannot be helpful in this case because of the roundness of the shape in combination with the low number of repetition of the pattern (you'll have to rely too much in the subsurf smoothing), while *Simple Deform* modifier does instead a great job on this aspect.

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks mr carlo for your advice and tutorials. Ill try to follow your steps and update here if i cannot find a way. Thanks again.

Comment: I know that I didn't went deeply down into each modeling aspect, but I preferred to present the *workflow/ I would have followed. The instruction for each modifier are probably better explained in the manual or in other question here on the site. BTW if you have any doubts, just write it down.

Comment: Hi @carlo, i stuck in the simple deform modifier. 
The output not as yours, mine looks weird. 

mine as follows in step "simple deform".

https://image.ibb.co/fvO395/Screen_Shot_2017_08_30_at_12_21_11_AM.png

Please advice why does this happen? THANKS in advance.

Comment: The modifier takes into account the object (an Empty in this case) location AND rotation. The rotation axis is by default the Z axis of the Empty. I think you should check the mutual orientation of your object and empty.